Multiplication of Real Characters
At the beginning of Sec 9.3. of Montgomery/Vaughan's Multiplicative NT the following comes without explanation:

Suppose that χ is a character modulo q, that $q = q_1q_2 $,  $  (q_1,
> q_2) = 1$, $χ = χ_1χ_2$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem we see that
$χ$ is a real character if and only if both $χ_1$ and $χ_2$ are real
characters.

Obviously if both $χ_1$ and $χ_2$ are real characters, so is their product. But how is the reverse direction true?

Let $n>0$. By the Chinese remainder theorem there is some $m>0$ such that $m\equiv n(\text{mod}\ q_1)$ and $m\equiv 1(\text{mod}\ q_2)$. Then:
$\chi(m)=\chi_1(m)\chi_2(m)=\chi_1(n)\chi_2(1)=\chi_1(n)$
And so $\chi_1(n)$ is real. Similarly, every value of $\chi_2$ is real.
